# ASP MVC5 deployment from TeamCity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, teamcity, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I have a website built with ASP MVC5.
Also I use Entity Framework 6 with Database First approach and edmx.
On production I already have database with a lot of data.
I'm using TeamCity for CI and would like to perform auto deployments.
I found Web Deployments and also tried to configure Publish profiles.
But 1 have some questions:

```
1. What about database? how to migrate, upgrade schema and data automatically? Are there any tools for that?
2. Could you describe how publish via Web Deploy works? I see connection string definition, etc. How it copies files to remote box, and how applies DB (schema, data migration?)
3. Also I configured IIS website for FTP upload deployment. How it connected with previous cases?
```

Comment: For 1. Have you looked at [migrate.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj618307.aspx) of EntityFramework? You will have to have your migration/schema update scripts as a command line or powershell script and then execute them as a [build step](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Command+Line) in teamcity.

Comment: are you talking about migrations in code First approach?